# Assembly exacutable does nothing when run

Tags: scripts, executable, assembler

I was following [this assembly tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_basic_syntax.htm) and had just gotten to my first piece of code. Following the tutorial, I assembled the program using `nasm -f elf hello.asm`, made it into an executable with `ld -m elf_i386 -s -o hello hello.o`, and finally ran it with `./hello`. The problem is nothing happened. Even if I tried to run the file any other way I could think of, absolutely nothing happened. I tried double-clicking the file, right-clicking then hitting run, and using `sudo ./hello`. Nothing has worked.

What did I do wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The example of the tutorial works fine. Are you sure you follow the steps correctly? There's no need for sudo.
You could also [use elf64/elf_x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246826/4970442) as output format/emulation linker: `nasm -f elf64 hello.asm; ld -s -o hello hello.o`

Comment: `strace ./hello` and `gdb ./hello`